# Cross domain Sails.js + Socket.io authorization

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cross-domain, authorization, sails.js

I'm working in an application which delivers *push* content to a group of web applications hosted in different domains. I'm using Sails.js and Socket.io, and structured it like this:

The client script, running on each web application's client's browser, is something like:

```
socket.on('customEvent', function(message){
    //do something with message on event trigger
}
```

And then, in the server, the event 'customEvent' is emitted when needed, and it works (e.g. on the `onConnect` event: `sails.io.emit('customEvent',{message ...}`).

But I'm facing a problem when it comes to handle authorization. The first approach I've tried is a cookie-based auth, as explained [here](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth) (by changing the `api/config/sockets.js` function `authorizeAttemptedSocketConnection`), but it isn't a proper solution for production and it isn't supported in browsers with a more restrictive cookie policy (due to their default prohibition to third-party cookies).

My question is: how to implement a proper cross-browser and cross-domain authorization mechanism using sails.js, that can be supported in socket.io's authorization process?

======

More details:

- I also tried adding a login with a well-known oauth provider (e.g. facebook), using [this example](https://github.com/stefanbuck/sails-social-auth-example) as a base. I've got the Passport session, but I'm still unable to authenticate from the client script (it only works in pages hosted by my node app directly).
- A JSONP request to obtain the session might be a solution, but it didn't work well in Safari. Plus I prefer the user to be authenticated in one of the web apps, rather than in my node application directly.

Comment: look into using redis for session store.. that'll help you going cross domain i think.

Comment: well indeed, it might help but I think that not in my particular case, because I have no access to each of the applications' session info for sharing identity or something, if that's what you meant. Or where you thinking something else?

Comment: How do you manage to open the websocket cross domain?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your routes must handle CORS mate. Example:

```
'/auth/logout': {
    controller: 'AuthController',
    action: 'logout',
    cors: '*'
},
```

Of course you can specify the list of ip your are accepting (and then replace the `'*'`).

Worth mentionning that you must specify where socket.io has to connect to (front-end JS):

```
socket = io.connect(API.url);
```

For any common http GET/PUT/POST/DELETE, please ensure that your ajax envelope goes with the credentials (cookie). For example with angular:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Let me know how it goes.