# how to send cookies for the socket.io handshake (sails.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to use the following code (extracted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/epadillas/5993856)):

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var request = require('request');
var xhr = require('socket.io-client/node_modules/xmlhttprequest');
var xhrOriginal = require('xmlhttprequest');

var myUrl = 'http://192.168.56.101:1337';
var cookieJar = request.jar();

// From socket.io-client's module 'xmlhttprequest', rewrie its XMLHttpRequest function.
xhr.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    this.XMLHttpRequest = xhrOriginal.XMLHttpRequest;
    xhrOriginal.XMLHttpRequest.apply(this, arguments);
    this.setDisableHeaderCheck(true); // Allow header modifications.

    // Rewrite the 'open' function.
    var openOriginal = this.open;
    this.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
        openOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
        var header = cookieJar.get({url: myUrl}).map(function(cookie) {
            return cookie.name + '=' + cookie.value;
        }).join('; ');
        this.setRequestHeader('cookie', header);
    };
};

// Send the cookie first before attempting to connect via socket-io,
// thus, avoiding the handshake error.
request.post({jar: cookieJar, url: myUrl}, function(err, resp, body) {
    var socket = io.connect(myUrl);
    socket.on('connecting', function() {
        console.log('(II) Connecting to server');
    });
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('(II) Successfully connected to server');
    });
    socket.on('error', function(reason) {
        console.log('(EE) Error connecting to server: ' + reason);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
        console.log('(II) Disconnected from server\n');
    });
});
```

To achieve a simpler handshake process with socket.io/sails.js, but I can't make it work.

Could someone provide an explanation on how to properly use it? Is it intended to run in the client as an imported script somehow? or as a served page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sails.js handles the socket handshake for you.  You can use the included `sails.io.js` and `socket.io.js` scripts for simple socket communication.  Can you say a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It's for cross-site. According to [this page](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets), at the bottom, it says that a previous request is necessary to allow the handshake process to be completed successfully. So, I was wondering if the script above can be used to avoid making such request or something similar. I've provided some more details about the issue I'm facing in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714828/cross-domain-sails-js-socket-io-authorization)